# How to remove or hide "Leave this page" button in confirm navigation of browsers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to remove/hide "Leave this page" button or want to trigger "Stay this page" button in confirm navigation of browsers?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {   
     return "Please close the another tabs to logout..";
 };
```

Comment: There's not much you can do, browsers are handling this event pretty privately (FF doesn't even pass your message). You can remove it by leaving the `onbeforeunload` handler out of your code. Triggering "Stay on this page" is not an option. Why wouldn't you close those tabs programmatically?

Comment: You can't force a browser to stay on your page by doing what you're asking.  If a user wants to leave, they can - it's their choice.  If it was possible to do what you're asking, it would be a spammers dream.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Is it possible for function call when click "Leave this page" button?

Comment: No, but you can attach `onunload` event to `window`, close the tabs in that handler.

Comment: Yes, sortof - see the related [`onunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload).  What you can do is limited there though, no new windows etc.

Comment: Really thanks for your replies..